# Some issue in SQL SELECT , AND , Not Equal to query

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

I have written a query

```
SELECT * 
FROM property_list 
WHERE property_zip=$my-zip 
      && property_visible='y' 
      && property_zip!=0
```

to fetch property with the registered user zip code, and have a condition where the property visible status is 'y' and property zip value not equal to zero.

the problem is...

if a registered user go to that page and the property with there zip code not available . Then it show the property with zip code zero & visibility 'n'.

I want, it don't show the property with zip code '0' & visibility 'n'

Comment: how about `where $my-zip <> ''` (or Null or whatever)

Comment: $my-zip store the registered user zip code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already comparing the property_zip value, there's no need to check if it isn't 0. The PHP code should filter that, because the query doesn't need to be executed (or prepared) if there's no ZIP code, right?

$my-zip has a dash in the variable name, which is not allowed in PHP. Try calling it $myZip, $my_zip or something of that sort.

Always escape any variables in an SQL query if it relies on user input. It's necessary to secure your site from [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection).

Also, if you're checking a string (which a ZIP code should usually be I think), that part of the query must be placed in quotes.

Putting it all together, I think the code you're looking for is something like the following:

```
// Check if the ZIP code isn't 0
if(!$myZip) {
    throw new Exception("Invalid ZIP code entered");
}

// Building a query, quoting in single quotes and escaping the value $myZip
$zipCodeQuery = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM property_list 
    WHERE property_zip = '".mysql_real_escape_string($myZip)."'
        AND property_visible = 'y'
";

// Execute query here
```

If this doesn't solve the problem, the issue is probably in the surrounding code or the input ZIP code.

Note: A better way of securing against SQL injection is to use prepared statements. A nice example using 'mysqli' can be found here: [mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Did it help? If so, please help me back by upvoting me ;-)